# Xamarin unable to connect to Mac from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin

When I am trying to connect mac with xamarin in visual studio 2015 it is not allowing me to login. It throws an exception saying couldn't connect to IP. Please try again, Whereas I have enabled the remote Login on the mac.
Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you connect normally via SSH?

Comment: Ping your IP in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be nice to put some logs here so we can be more helpful. You can see the Xamarin logs by just going to Help on Visual Studio and then Xamarin>Open Logs. Make sure you can connect to your mac server via RDP ( I use Vnc Viewer).

Secondly I had a similar problem, I couldn't connect to my mac build server from Visual Studio and [this is how I fixed my problem](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/181463/#Comment_181463) and that also helped other people. Hopefully it will helpful for you as well.

And finally please remember to install all the xamarin updates on both your windows machine and Mac Build server before trying any of these, Xamarin versions must be identical in order to not to see weird problems.

For Xamarin documentation regarding with Connecting to the Mac, [please click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/).